# When a figure environment contain many figures so that the paper is not long enough, how to make these figure be inextenso typed?

Tags: floats, two-column

I want to make each figure has its on `subcaption`, so I have to put these figures in a `figure` environment. However, the paper is not long(high) enough to type all these figures, and the `\pagebreak` or `\newpage` is unavailable in figure environment. How can I solve this problem.

And another question: Why these picture is not centering since I use `\centering` in the figure environment.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareCaptionOption{english}[]{
\renewcommand\figurename{Fig}
\renewcommand\tablename{Tab}}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{english}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=66mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{example-image-a}
\label{fig:fig8a}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=66mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 1}\label{fig:example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=66mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 2}\label{fig:example-image-c}

\end{subfigure}


\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=66mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 3}\label{fig:example-image-d}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=66mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 4}\label{fig:example-image-e}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=66mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 5}\label{fig:example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\bicaption{谢谢}{Thank you very much!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\ContinuedFloat` from `caption` package. I have made some minor changes like using `\columnwidth` and `0.9\linewidth` for `\includegraphics` and adding `\centering` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\DeclareCaptionOption{english}[]{
\renewcommand\figurename{Fig}
\renewcommand\tablename{Tab}}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{english}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{continued}{#1~#2 (Cont.)}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=continued}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{example-image-a}
\label{fig:fig8a}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 1}\label{fig:example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 2}\label{fig:example-image-c}

\end{subfigure}


\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 3}\label{fig:example-image-d}
\end{subfigure}
\bicaption{谢谢}{Thank you very much!}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 4}\label{fig:example-image-e}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example 5}\label{fig:example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\bicaption{谢谢}{Thank you very much!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DXL Just remove the first `\bicaption{谢谢}{Thank you very much!}`.